# Bridging Azure Web Apps and Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-service-fabric

I have a few Azure Web Sites/Apps running currently. I've been looking into Service Fabric as a way to off load some long running work; similarly to what would happen in a Worker Role. I know you can host web applications in Service Fabric, but I really prefer not to move our web sites/apps into it right now.

What would be the best way to connect my current web apps to a Reliable Actor for instance? After looking through the documentation and videos, I get the feeling that you can only get an Actor Proxy if you're hosting in the fabric already. Outside of that, I can imagine I could always setup a queue of some sort, but if there's another option I'd be open to hearing about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a queue like Azure Service Bus /Storage Queue instead of a web-api because of the long running nature of the jobs. Calling an actor directly from the web api would result in a timeout. So you'd end up needing some kind of queue anyway. 
Use [reminders](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-timers-reminders/) inside your actors to periodically see if there's work in the queue.

Comment: Make this the answer because you're right about the queues.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't descriptive enough in my answer but I wasn't suggesting that your API calls wait for the actors to do the work. An API call could add an item to a reliable queue in a stateful service to do the work and return immediately, or add a reminder on an actor to do the work later on. Using Service Bus or Storage Queue would also work but there's no need for it IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You’re right, you can’t access an actor directly. You can have a web API within your Service Fabric application - a stateless service - that will expose the necessary endpoints for interacting with your web sites/apps.

Take a look at this article in the documentation for more details on how to do this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi/.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a solution for this, it still has a bit of way to go. https://github.com/s-innovations/MessageProcessor.ServiceFabric

But maybe some of the fundamental ideas behind it is reusable and I also came from worker roles and migrated into service fabric.

The problem is that the workload is very different and require different type of machine hardware and one of the goals was to not have the expensive machines running when they are not doing anything.

The solution is a service farbric application that can be deployed to a cluster running on 5 extra small nodes (cost little less than a A1 VM).

It will monitor a set of queues (configuration based) and whenever a message is in them, it will deploy a service (also configuration based) to the cluster that can pull messages of the queue. When it has idled for some time it will remove the service again.

Together with VM Scale Sets, it will create new vm sizes based on demand and shut them down again as explained above.

Everything is queue/topic based and from the azure website applications you can queue workload simply by posting messages to the servicebus topic/queue.

This is the project that helps creating message handles. 
https://github.com/s-innovations/S-Innovations.Azure.MessageProcessor

Vote it up if you find it interesting and I will see If i can get around to writing some more documentation.